# Novel where a guy made an experiment on imaginary time travel without any time machine

Tags: story-identification, books, time-travel

I remember reading an unusual book where a guy made an experiment on imaginary time travel without any time machine. He thought that any day was kinda his past according to a future day and sometimes his day is a future where he got from his real day that was yesterday.

At first this was just a pure thought experiment but then some strange things started happening - like he met people who knew him even though he didn't remember them at all. Or people remembered things about him he didn't do, etc.

I read it about 6-7 years ago and it was written probably in the 70-s or 80-s.

Comment: I'm afraid that's [an entire genre](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/MentalTimeTravel) of its own. Can you provide any additional details? What kind of job did this guy have? Was he from the United States? Did he have a reason for time travel, or was he just curious?Do you remember anything about what the cover looked like? Hardback or softback? We have guidance on further details to consider at https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question

Comment: This ability tends to be called *chronesthesia*. Can you remember if this term was used in the book?